# Why does Cygwin fail to install saying "can't open C:\cygwin\/var/log/setup.log for writing"?

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install the latest Cygwin. Even when I accept almost all the settings default values, it fails to set up, saying:

> can't open C:\cygwin/var/log/setup.log for writing

I run Windows XP SP2 Professional English and am the administrator (and choose the same account for Cygwin). Is that "/" pair in the path the reason for the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: What version of windows? are you selecting to run as administrator? In vista and 7, even if you are admin, they do not run installers with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the Cygwin folder `C:\cygwin` and reinstall.